# why doesn't the added element get saved in the final list?

Tags: c, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

```
struct node* addBeginning(struct node *head)
{

    struct node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int new;

    printf("\nAdd a new element that will be placed at the beginning of the list\n");
    scanf("%d", &new);

    tmp -> data = new;
    tmp -> link = head;
    head = tmp;

    printf("The list after the insertion\n");
    display(head);
    return head;
}
```

when i run display(head) in the function, it does actually print a new element at the beginning of the list. the problem is when i run display(head) in main(); it only prints out the list without the newly added node. i also build the function addEnd to add a node at the end of the list and there it prints out the list with the new node at the end. so whats the problem here?

the whole code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "node4.h"

void create();
void display(struct node *head);
struct node *addBeginning(struct node *head);
struct node *addEnd(struct node *last, struct node *head);

int main()
{
    create();
    return 0;
}

void create()
{

    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node)), *tmp;
    int n, num;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory can not be allocated");
        return;
    }

    printf("How many nodes do you want to create?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n <= 0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a number greater than 0 or '-1' to exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n == -1)
            exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter the elements to be stored in the nodes\n");
    printf("Element at node 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    head->data = num;
    head->link = NULL;
    tmp = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        struct node *current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (current == NULL)
            printf("Memory cannot be allocated for node %d", i + 2);

        printf("Element at node %d: ", i + 2);
        scanf("%d", &num);

        current->data = num;
        current->link = NULL;
        tmp->link = current;
        tmp = current;
    }

    display(head);
    addBeginning(head);
    display(head);
    addEnd(tmp, head);
    display(head);
    return;
}

void display(struct node *head)
{

    struct node *current;
    current = head;
    if (current == NULL)
        printf("List is empty");

    printf("The elements in the linked list are: ");
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        (current->link == NULL) ? printf("%d ", current->data) : printf("%d -> ", current->data);
        current = current->link;
    }
    return;
}

struct node *addBeginning(struct node *head)
{

    struct node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int my_new;

    printf("\nAdd a new element that will be placed at the beginning of the list\n");
    scanf("%d", &my_new);

    tmp->data = my_new;
    tmp->link = head;
    head = tmp;

    printf("The list after the insertion\n");
    return head;
}

struct node *addEnd(struct node *last, struct node *head)
{

    struct node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int end;

    printf("\nAdd a new element at the end of the list\n");
    scanf("%d", &end);

    tmp->data = end;
    last->link = tmp;
    tmp->link = NULL;

    printf("The list after insertion\n");
    return head;
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball says the caller of this, which you chose *not* to include for whatever reason, isn't doing this: `head = addBeginning(head);` , it's just doing this: `addBeginning(head);` . So hows about a proper [mcve] that we can use to verify whether my crystal ball is telling the truth.

Comment: @WhozCraig looks like your crystal ball wasn't lying. but why does this work for addEnd(head); though? i did the exact same thing with addEnd(head); and addBeginning(); so why does the list for one function get updated and for the other one doesn't?

Comment: Neither will work with a naked call when `head` is initially NULL, and I won't believe otherwise until shown with real code. The same crystal ball tells me your primer code in main (that we *still* cannot see) is starting with a head pointing to a single node. prior to the call to `addEnd` (or `addBeginning`, make no difference). That means a lot, because appending to the end of a non-empty list will not alter what `head` in `main` points to (so it "works") but prepending before `head` requires changing `head` at the caller site, so it fails.

Comment: thanks for the tip @mitchell but it looks like that didn't cause the problem. WhozCraig was right

Comment: @WhozCraig i just posted the whole code